# Invalid syntax - Basic VBA query

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hopefully this is a simple fix problem.

I have a VBA query which is trying to import 100 or so practically identical (same columns, different data) csv files into one table.

whenever i try to run the macro, it doesn't work and gets

> invalid syntax error

```
Public Function Import()
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean


blnHasFieldNames = True

strPath = "C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\Riskmodels\"

strTable = "table"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")


Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
      TableName:=strTable, _
      FileName:=strPathFile, _
      HasFieldName:=True

      strFile = Dir()
Loop

End Function
```

any idea why this doesn't work?

thanks

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: ah that would help. How do i tell? I have the VBA going to a macro and the macro just returns a generic error

Comment: its this bit: HasFieldName:=True

Comment: `HasFieldNames:=`

Comment: Thanks, Now I have "Named Argument Not Found", will see what google knows about that :/

Comment: hang on, think that's done it - thanks Nathan!

Answer (score 2):

Named argument should be `HasFieldNames:=`